# Error en mi código: no match for 'operator >>' en c++. Al querer usar cin >> con un elemento de una estructura

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo a usar las estructuras en c++ y quiero insertar un dato de tipo entero y me sale el error del título. En concreto en la línea: `cout<<"Edad: "; cin>>c1.age;` al querer insertar un valor de tipo entero en una variable de una estructura, ¿alguien podría decirme que tengo de mal? aquí el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std; 
struct corredor
{
    char name[30];
    int age[10];
    char sex[30];
    char club[40];
    char categ[30];
}c1;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Nombre: "; cin.getline(c1.name,30,'\n');
    cout<<"Edad: "; cin>>c1.age;    //En este renglón tengo el error
    cout<<"Sexo: "; cin.getline(c1.sex,30,'\n');
    cout<<"Club: "; cin.getline(c1.sex,40,'\n');
    if ((c1.age)<=18)
    {
        c1.categ = "JUVENIL";
    }
    else if ((c1.age)<=40)
    {
        c1.categ = "SEÑOR";
    }
    else if((c1.age)>40)
    {
        c1.categ = "VETERANO";
    }
    cout<<"El corredor con nombre "<<c1.name;
    cout<<" de edad "<<c1.age;
    cout<<" de sexo "<<c1.sex;
    cout<<" del club "<<c1.club;
    cout<<" competirá en la categoría "<<c1.categ;
    
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c1.age` es un arreglo de 10 enteros, no un solo entero, por eso no encuentra un `operator>>` adecuado

Comment: Muchas gracias, si era eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable miembro `corredor::age` es de tipo `int[10]`; no existen sobrecargas del operador `>>` que acepten una formación de diez enteros. Seguramente te equivocaste y no querías guardar diez edades para el corredor si no sólo una:

```
struct corredor
{
    char name[30];
    int age; // Un entero, no diez.
    char sex[30];
    char club[40];
    char categ[30];
}c1;
```

Por otro lado, en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) moderno, no se usan formaciones de caracteres para guardar textos, usa en su lugar variables de tipo `std::string`:

```
struct corredor
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    std::string sex;
    std::string club;
    std::string categ;
}c1;
```

Si además seguimos un diseño más robusto, deberías usar enumeraciones para aquellos datos cuyos valores sean un conjunto cerrado:

```
enum sexo { MUJER, HOMBRE };
enum categoria { JUVENIL, SENIOR, VETERANO };

struct corredor
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    sexo sex;
    std::string club;
    categoria categ;
}c1;
```

Finalmente, puedes sobrecargar el operador `<<` para mostrar `corredor` por pantalla:

```
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const correcor &c)
{
    o << "El corredor con nombre " << c.name
      << " de edad " << c.age
      << " de sexo ";

    switch (c.sex)
    {
        case MUJER: o << " Mujer"; break;
        case HOMBRE: o << " Hombre"; break;
    }

    o << " competirá en la categoría ";

    switch (c.categ)
    {
        case JUVENIL: o << " Juvenil"; break;
        case SENIOR: o << " Senior"; break;
        case VETERANO: o << " Veterano"; break;
    }

    return o;
}
```